# How to move and copy files/read files from Azure Blob into databricks and transform the file and send to target bob container

Tags: azure-databricks

I am new beginner in to Azure Databricks. I wanted to know how can we copy and read files from Azure Blob source container into databricks, transform as needed and sent back to target container in blob.

Can some provide python code here?

Answer (score 0):

> It's not recommended to copy files to DBFS. I would suggest you to mount the blob storage account and then you can read/write files to the storage account.

You can mount a Blob storage container or a folder inside a container to Databricks File System (DBFS). The mount is a pointer to a Blob storage container, so the data is never synced locally.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/azure-storage

> Do not Store any Production Data in Default DBFS Folders

[image].

**Reference:** [Azure Databricks - best practices](https://github.com/Azure/AzureDatabricksBestPractices/blob/master/toc.md).